# Как правильно использовать transition?

Tags: css, hover

Здравствуйте. Делаю меню под телефон. Чтобы было красивое появление, хочу добавить динамики.

```
.menu-phone > li {
  display: none;
  transition: 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-phone:active li {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-phone:hover li {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Но листы все равно сразу видны, не срабатывает `transition: 2s;`. Пока не добавлял

```
.menu-phone:hover li {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

то они срабатывали в обратную сторону (исчезали), но без `hover` лист тогда сразу исчезает обратно.

Comment: добавьте html, не ясно на что нужно наводить, если элемент пустой, так как внутри него вы все скрыли

Comment: пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3eqdby4s/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transition` свойство не работает на свойство `display:block\none;` ! Используйте без него или используйте `visibility: hidden`, так же можно играть с высотой

[Пример на jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpe62for/)

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 0px;
  background: violet;
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
.menu-phone > li {
  display: none;
  transition: 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-phone:active li {
  display: block;
  transition: 2s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-phone:hover li {
  display: block;
  transition: 2s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: попробовал - не сработало